# CSS Layout - best way to have a wrapper

Tags: html, css, layout

Isn't the first time I want all content inside all sections are in a container with a max-width, but the only solution is duplicate html tags. Something like this:

```
<body>
  <section class="one">
    <div class="wrapper">
      // content for one
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="two">
  // There is a background here
    <div class="wrapper">
      // content for two
    </div>
   </section>
  <section class="three">
    <div class="wrapper">
      // content for three
    </div>
   </section>
  <section class="four">
  // There is a background here
    <div class="wrapper">
      // content for four
    </div>
   </section>
</body>
```

Putting a div "wrapper" inside looks like the only solution to control every section with a max-width/centered and keeps the ability to put a full-width backgound in few section.

I don't like this solution, is a div duplicated for every section with same properties. If someday I change my mind and want remove it or I need to do it in every section or I need to remove css to that selector. Its look not semantical for me.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a div like this

```
<div id="maindiv">
<div id="sitecontainer"> 
<!-- inner content -->
</div>
</div>
```

Then you can control max width from one place for all section.  IF you don't want max width for a section, remove the site container div from within that section.  You change your mind on the width? Change it in one place.  You decide to go 100% width, change the width to 100% inside that div.  Makes it easy to manage sitewide..

Your css

```
#sitecontainer { float: left; width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; }
#maindiv { float: left; width: 100%; }
```

Then if you add another div,

```
<div id="secondarydiv">
<div id="sitecontainer">
// content still 1000px centered
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: By doing it this way, it makes it easy to manage across css media queries for scaling the site based on width of screen/device.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get it. Isn't the same what did above? (and why float? No need float to do that)

Comment: I was just stating that that is how I would set it up.  I use float so that the margin will be taken into account.  You can also use display: block or another method like that; however, I use floats for alignment.  I don't know of another way of doing it other than that.

Comment: Actually, I don't think pseudo elements will work in this scenario anyways.  You'll still need inner div's to make the pseudo work.  As far as from what I can see.  I think a container div is your only option.

Comment: Yes, I can't see how to avoid inner div. I just put a max-width and margin auto. It works.

Comment: Well if this helps you can accept the answer as accepted as there are no other options available.

Comment: Thanks, but its better wait for another opinions, because your html semantic solution (the problem I would like to solve) is the same as mine.